# Is it possible to initialize a Float Action Button in different class and call it from another class?

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm a beginner in android and I'm doing a little exercises on FAB. So I want to know is it possible to initialize a FAB in another class and calling it from another ? I've been looking a sample for this kind of condition but I did not found anything. Please enlighten me. If is possible I would like a sample code for reference.

Comment: Why would you want to do this again? You would only need the FAB shown on the visible activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible. But remember its also possible to define a custom xml layout file for your desired FAB. If this fulfills your needs its a much cleaner solution. You can define pretty much from xml for a FAB. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fab"
    app:fabSize="@drawable/fab_size"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_color"
    app:rippleColor="@color/fab_ripple"
    app:useCompatPadding="true" />
```